# Error al agregar documento nuevo a firestore desde una función gatillada por un botón

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, crud

estoy trabajando en una app Web en Firebase, que utliza Hosting y Firestore. La idea es poder hacer una CRUD para productos en un inventario. Esto es meramente educativo.
La vista es **agregar.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Gestor de Inventario</title>

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.2.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.2.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <!-- initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Formulario para ingresar un nuevo producto</h1>

    <form class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="pure-control-group">
                <label for="name">Nombre</label>
                <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
                <span class="pure-form-message-inline">This is a required field.</span>
            </div>

            <div class="pure-control-group">
                <label for="precio">Precio Unidad</label>
                <input id="precio" type="number" placeholder="10000" value="100">
            </div>

            <div class="pure-control-group">
                <label for="stock">Stock</label>
                <input id="cant_stock" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="10">
            </div>

            <div class="pure-controls">
                <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" onclick="submitButton()">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <a href="/index.html">Volver al inicio</a>

    <script src="/src/agregar.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

por su parte, el código asociado **agregar.js**:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",event=>{
    const app = firebase.app();
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    window.db = db;
});


function submitButton(){
    const inventarioRef = window.db.collection('inventario');
    //console.log(window.db);
    const nombre = document.getElementById("name");
    const precio = document.getElementById("precio");
    const cant_stock = document.getElementById("cant_stock");
    let obj = {
        nombre: nombre.value,
        precio: precio.value,
        cant_stock: cant_stock.value
    };
    if(obj.nombre != "" && obj.precio != "" && obj.cant_stock != ""){
        console.log("Se agrego: " + JSON.stringify(obj));
        /* La siguiente consulta jamas se realiza */
        inventarioRef.add(obj).then(ref =>{
            console.log(ref.id);
        });
    }
    else{
        alert("Debes completar todos los campos !");
    }
}
```

El resultado es que al hacer click en el botón, la página se actualiza pero la consulta jamás es realizada.
Si bien la operación se ejecuta correctamente en el bloque del "DOMContentLoaded", al realizar la consulta dentro de otra función esta no se realiza.

PD: Realizar operaciones en la parte del "DOMContentLoaded" siempre funciona, pero si quiero realizar la consulta luego de completar un formulario y dar click al botón esta no se realiza.

EDIT: Probé con los siguientes cambios en **agregar.js** :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",event =>{
    const app = firebase.app();
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    console.log("Referencia a la base de datos, justo despues de cargar la pagina: " + db);
    window.db = db;
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",enviar);

});


function submitButton(){
    try{
        console.log("Comenzando la funcion ");
        console.log("Referencia a la base de datos, al presionar el boton: " + window.db);
        const inventarioRef = window.db.collection('inventario');
        const nombre = document.getElementById("name");
        const precio = document.getElementById("precio");
        const cant_stock = document.getElementById("cant_stock");
        let obj = {
            nombre: nombre.value,
            precio: precio.value,
            cant_stock: cant_stock.value
        };
        if(obj.nombre != "" && obj.precio != "" && obj.cant_stock != ""){
            console.log("Se agrego: " + JSON.stringify(obj));
            /* La siguiente consulta jamas se realiza */
            const query = inventarioRef.add(obj).then(ref =>{
                console.log(ref.id);
            }).catch(e =>{
                console.log(e)
            });
            console.log(query);
            return query;
        }
        else{
            alert("Debes completar todos los campos !");
        }
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }


}

async function enviar(){
    console.log("calling");
    var result =  await submitButton();
    console.log("Resultado: " + result);
}
```

Y la salida por consola es la siguiente:

*Navigated to [http://localhost:5000/views/agregar.html](http://localhost:5000/views/agregar.html_)*

*Referencia a la base de datos, justo despues de cargar la pagina: [object Object] agregar.js:5:13*

*calling agregar.js:48:13*

*Comenzando la funcion agregar.js:14:17*

*Referencia a la base de datos, al presionar el boton: [object Object] agregar.js:15:17*

_Se agrego: {"nombre":"prueba3","precio":"100","cant_stock":"10"} agregar.js:26:21_

*Promise { : "pending" }*

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con *no se realiza*? ¿Entra en ese bloque o no? ¿Conecta a Firebase o no? ¿Depuraste tu código? Da más detalles sobre la situación: *depuré esto y ni siquiera entra aquí... o sí entra, pero no trae datos... o esta variable está en blanco o es undefined*. O sea, tienes que aprender a depurar tu código y te ahorrarás horas de trabajo y muchos dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Estimado agradezco la respuesta !!

Comment: Estimado agradezco la respuesta !! No se realiza: Desde la consola de Firebase, veo que el dato que agregue no aparece, es decir, jamàs se ejecutò la consulta. A firebase si conecta, todo funciona bien dentro del scope que se ejecuta cuando el DOMContentLoaded se gatilla. Tienes razòn, depurarè con màs cuidado.

Comment: Tú tienes un control cuando agregas: `console.log(ref.id);` ¿Estás revisando la consola de Javascript? ¿El código entra ahí o no, o imprime el alert `"Debes completar todos los campos !`?

Comment: Si he revisado la consola, este es el resultado: **console.log("Se agrego: " + JSON.stringify(obj));** esa linea si se ejecuta. Luego viene la consulta, la cual no imprime nada, y cuando pongo un console.log("Debug") despues del catch de la consulta, si se ve. Es decir, se muestra todo antes y despues de la consulta !

Comment: No, eso no es el resultado. En la consola de Javascript dede poner otra cosa, algo como: `Se agrego: { aquí el objeto JSON que se creó al llamar a JSON.stringify }` Para verlo, debes activar la consola en las opciones de desarrollador del navegador.